# Battery and External Power without Diodes Circuit

Tags: power, circuit-design, charging, circuit-protection, usb-c

I'm designing a power system for my project. My project is powered from standard 18650 li-ion battery (or other 3.7V battery) or from USB 5V power source. Originally, my requirements were broader, I wanted it to support 20V input too, so I have a MP8860 buck-boost in my current design, which is large (not really a problem), but it's also pretty expensive and requires a gang of external components, and considering what it can do it feels like a big overkill for my application.

Currently in my project, battery meets USB DC-IN through two Schottky, all of that is fed into the buck-boost, the output should be 5V. At least that was the design, I haven't ordered any prototypes yet. External power input not only powers the devices, but also initiates battery charging.

Requirements changed, it was decided to simplify the things and abandon 20V power. So now I have just 5V input. The thing is, the system needs 5V, and I would really like to keep my 5V at 5V without a voltage drop from Schottky. Not that I'm too crazy about precision, but if it's not too hard, I would prefer to have 5V. After googling I didn't really find anything suitable, so I tried some pen-and-paper creativity and tried to build different circuits of diodes, mosfets etc., this puzzle solving was fun, but I didn't come up with any solution that I would call elegant and viable enough in terms of component count, reliability and functionality. But my very limited experience also limits what I can come up with.

Anyway, the questions are:

**1)** How do I combine 3.7V battery output boosted to 5V with USB 5V input, so that my target devices always receive full 5V either directly from USB or battery's boosted 3.7->5. I want to have an ON/OFF switch that will cut power from the device (mechanically), and I would want zero off current. Yet while device is off, I should obviously be able to charge battery. This is the main question, and if you could describe or roughly sketch a circuit that would do just that (always provide 5V output, no shutdowns if charger removed). The only thing I thought of is a boost converter with passthrough, and battery is Schottkied into USB DC-IN line, all of that goes into boost converter. If it's 3.5V, it's boosted, if line is at 5V (which means USB power), it just passes it through. Power off and charging aren't hard to design around it, I believe. Anyway, there have to be better ideas.

**2)** I'm using Type-C usb port. Is it right that I should include 20V input protection just in case? It's just a pair of components, including dedicated chip, which is no problem to add. I have a lot of space, and I want to make things safe. So protect against 20V or no need?

**3)** Do I need any charger negotiation? Considering the device will use over 1A at 5V most of the time, I will need a 2A charger to charge it. Do I have to do anything to make sure a compatible charger provides the required current, or can I assume the necessary 2A will always be available as long as the charger is able to provide so much current. I really like Type-C and making it a Micro USB would feel like returning to Stone Age for me, but if it makes my life a lot easier, I will consider it (although I would still want an answer about how to implement it with Type-C).

Also, I have to admit, I'm not entirely sure what performance of my current buck-boost MP8860 would be if its input voltage is 4.8 and output should be 5V, in other words, if I keep my current circuit with both power sources Schottkying together, would I get 4.8V output if USB voltage is just passed through, or would I get boosted to 5V although it's such close voltage, or would I get maybe some weird oscillations because 4.8 and 5 are so close. As I said, it was intended to withstand 20V input, although it looks like it should work with 5V. In other words, I think my circuit should already work, but I'm looking for a smaller solution without price/space/complexity overkill, but safe and reliable enough.

Comment: I'm aware MP8860 can give 1A out, tbh it's likely it would be enough, I'm just staying on a safe side now

Comment: Aren't there ICs around which handle exactly that? You're not the first to have a battery powered device which can be charged while running. If you use USB, I'd recommend not just drawing current, someone will plug it into their PC and it might damage it.